# What does this warning on a MacBook Pro mean: “USB Device Needs Power”

Tags: macbook

I just reconnected my MacBook Pro to all of its normal devices for "desktop" type operation. Now I'm getting a warning: USB Device Needs Power - Connect "Internal Memory Card Reader" to a USB port on this Mac. What does that mean?

Comment: I guess you could open it up and find the internal memory card reader and plug it into a set of usb pins on the motherboard. that's a complete guess though.

Comment: if you unplug some other USB devices, does the message go away? you may have exceeded the amount of power available to the USB bus internally.

Comment: @FrankThomas Universal Serial Bus Bus?? I vote we now call USB BusBus

Comment: A single USB port can only handle a certain amount of devices if those devices are drawing power from that USB devices, even if they are not, then there is still a limit on the number of devices that can be connected to that port.  Unless you provide specifics on each device this question will be difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the Memory Card Reader connected to a USB port on another device that is connected to the MacBook.  The warning is telling you to connect that card reader directly to a USB port on your MacBook rather than indirectly via another device.

Comment: This sounds right.  Something isn't getting enough power.  If it had enough power before but not now then something changed.  The devices were not plugged in the same place, a powered hub lost power, a loose connection somewhere, or whatever.  USB port on a MacBook Pro should provide 1.5 amps of power, an unpowered hub only 500 mA, a powered hub typically 900 mA.